# PanResponder React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with PanResponder in React-native.
I don't understand how use it ...
my code :

```
export default class Index_preferences extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onPanResponderMove: this._handlePanResponderMove,
      onPanResponderGrant: this._handlePanResponderGrant,
    });
  }

_handlePanResponderMove(event, gestureState) {
    console.log(gestureState);
  }

  _handlePanResponderGrant(event, gestureState) {
    console.log(gestureState);
  }

componentTag() {
   return tabTag.map((item, id) => {
      return(
        <View key={id} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
          <Text>Here</Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
}

render() {
  return (
    <View> {this.componentTag()} </View>
  );
}
```

}

But nothing happens my console display nothing

Thanks !

Comment: I found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this post
Solution : 
add :

```
onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
```

in

```
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onPanResponderMove: this._handlePanResponderMove,
      onPanResponderGrant: this._handlePanResponderGrant,
    });
```

Comment: It's probably enough just to add `onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture`